# Nested loops in Less

Tags: less

I have some nested loops in Less.
It should create css rules for padding with 3 sizes and 4 direction.
Code sample:

```
@sizes: normal, small, large;
@size-normal: 1em;
@size-small: 0.8 * @size-normal;
@size-large: 1.2 * @size-normal;


.l-padding {
   @directions: top, left, right, bottom;

   .s(@i: length(@sizes)) when (@i > 0) {
     .s((@i - 1));
     .d(@j: length(@directions)) when (@j > 0) {
       .d((@j - 1));
       @dir: extract(@directions, @j);
       @s: extract(@sizes, @i);
       @size: "size-@{s}";
       &_@{dir}_@{s} {
         .l-padding-mixin(@dir, @@size);
       }
    }
    .d();
  }
  .s();
}
```

I don't know where is the problem but it compile to many duplacates. However each independet loop do their job.

```
.l-padding_top_normal {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.l-padding_left_normal {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.l-padding_right_normal {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.l-padding_bottom_normal {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.l-padding_top_normal {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.l-padding_left_normal {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.l-padding_right_normal {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.l-padding_bottom_normal {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.l-padding_top_normal {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

...

.l-padding_top_normal {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.l-padding_top_small {
  padding-top: 0.8em;
}
.l-padding_left_small {
  padding-left: 0.8em;
}
.l-padding_right_small {
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}
.l-padding_bottom_small {
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
}
.l-padding_top_normal {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.l-padding_left_normal {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.l-padding_right_normal {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.l-padding_bottom_normal {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

...
```

To many duplicates. Can any one help with this?

**UPD**
thanks to @Harry find solution:

```
.l-padding-mixin(@direction, @size: 1em) {
  padding-@{direction}: @size;
}

@sizes: normal, small, large;

@size-normal: 1em;
@size-small: 0.8 * @size-normal;
@size-large: 1.2 * @size-normal;

//==== layouts ====
.l-padding {
  @directions: top, left, right, bottom;
  @i: length(@sizes);
  @j: length(@directions);

  .d(@j) when (@j > 0) {
    .d((@j - 1));
    @dir: extract(@directions, @j);
    @s: extract(@sizes, @i);
    @size: "size-@{s}";
    &_@{dir}_@{s} {
      .l-padding-mixin(@dir, @@size);
    }
  }

  .-(@i) when (@i > 0) {
    .-((@i - 1));
    .d(@j);
  } .-(@i);
}
```

Comment: I know a solution (which is to move the entire `.d()` loop outside of the `.s()` loop and it works fine) but I can't give a 100% perfect explanation of why the current code produces duplicates. I think it is more to do with the way Less loops and mixin calls are handled than any error with the code.

Comment: @Harry, thank you. This helps to me.

Comment: the duplicates were there because each `.s` iteration defines *new* `.d` mixin (that stack on top of each other when the whole thing is expanded in the same scope with the initial mixin call).